# MySQL: multiple where + multiple group by index

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

I have simple table `temp` with any data and 5 columns:

[image]

I need to run such query:

`select c,d from temp where (a='633' and b='581' and e='1') group by c,d`

I've tried to add different indexes to prevent `Using temporary/filesort`:

index(a,b,e,c,d) - where clause indexed but group by using temporary table and filesort
index(c,d,a,b,e) - group by indexed but where clause not indexed

Does such index exist? How to optimize query in such situations?